# $Y_n=X_1X_2 \cdots X_n \to 0$ in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

We consider $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ positive and independent random variables with $E[X_n]=c$, where $c\in(0,1),\forall n$. If $Y_n=X_1 \cdots X_n$, then $Y_n \to 0$ in probability.

I'm trying to use the defition: $$\begin{align*} \lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X_1 \cdot X_2 ... X_n|>\epsilon)& =1-\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdots X_n|\leq\epsilon) \\ &=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdots X_n\leq\epsilon) \end{align*}$$ and I don't know what to do with this. I'm also wondering if in this case you can use WLLN(i'm saying not because $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are not iid).

A hint will be very helpful.Thanks!
P.S.:I'm a newbie in probability theory.

Comment: You might find it easier to prove that $\log(Y_n) \to -\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the independence of the random variables, show that $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \cdots X_n \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(X_1 \cdots X_n) = \frac{c^n}{\epsilon}$$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Letting $n \to \infty$ gives

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_1 \cdots X_n \geq \epsilon)=0$$ as $c \in (0,1)$.

**Remark** In fact, $Y_n$ converges almost surely to $0$, this follows e.g. from the Borel Cantelli lemma and the above estimate.